# Is there a way to extract only the values from a dictionary object to add to a list, using the lamba function?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I am experimenting using lambda functions to create a list that contains only the values of a particular key to a list.

I have the following:

```
names = None
names = list(map(lambda restaurant: dict(name=restaurant['name']
                                          ).values(), yelp_restaurants))
names

# This is what I want for the list:
# ['Fork & Fig',
#  'Salt And Board',
#  'Frontier Restaurant',
#  'Nexus Brewery',
#  "Devon's Pop Smoke",
#  'Cocina Azul',
#  'Philly Steaks',
#  'Stripes Biscuit']
```

What I get however, is the following:

```
[dict_values(['Fork & Fig']),
 dict_values(['Salt And Board']),
 dict_values(['Frontier Restaurant']),
 dict_values(['Nexus Brewery']),
 dict_values(["Devon's Pop Smoke"]),
 dict_values(['Cocina Azul']),
 dict_values(['Philly Steaks']),
 dict_values(['Stripes Biscuit'])]
```

Is there a way to only pass the values, an eliminate the redundant 'dict_values' prefix?

Comment: can you show your original data structure please, might be an easier way to achieve your desired result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are using to create `names` is a bit redundant:

```py
names = list(map(lambda restaurant: dict(name=restaurant['name']
                                          ).values(), yelp_restaurants))
```

The control flow that you have outlined is "from a `list` of `dict` entries called `yelp_restaurants`, I want to create a `dict` of each `name` and grab the values from each `dict` and put that in a `list`."

Why? Don't get hung up on `lambda` functions yet. Start simple, like a for loop:

```py
names = []

for restaurant in yelp_restaurants:
    names.append(restaurant['name'])
```

Look at how much simpler that is. It does exactly what you want, just get the `name` and stuff it into a list. You can put that in a list comprehension:

```py
names = [restaurant['name'] for restaurant in yelp_restaurants]
```

Or, if you *really* need to use `lambda`, now it's much easier to see what you actually want to accomplish

```py
names = list(map(lambda x: x['name'], yelp_restaurants))
```

Remember, the `x` in `lambda x:` is each member of the iterable `yelp_restaurants`, so `x` is a `dict`. With that in mind, you are using direct access on `name` to extract what you want.

Comment: In the last example, you can get a moderate speedup by using `operator.itemgetter('name')` in place of the `lambda` - but that's a bit of an advanced topic. The list comprehension is preferable anyway.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper definitely so, but I don't think optimization is or should be the goal right now

Comment: @C.Nivs Thanks, all I needed was the last part. Is there something that made my question bothersome which necessitated a down-vote and a condescending answer?

Comment: @Eduardo I'm not your downvoter, and I wouldn't make assumptions as to who is. If my answer came off as condescending, that wasn't the intent, so apologies on that front

Comment: @Eduardo: I see nothing condescending in this answer. No need to bite a hand that is feeding you, is there?

Comment: @C.Nivs, I didn't assume it was you, sorry I made that seem accusatory. 

Hovercraft Full Of Eels To me it seemed like it was, I'm not biting/mad. I was honestly asking for advice/suggestion on how to word my questions, because when I ask on here, I seem to offend people with no intent to do so.

Comment: @Eduardo: if you want advice then this is it: accept that when you post code, any answer may criticize the code, and that is often part of the answer. This is neither condescending nor rude, but rather to be instructive. Accept and welcome the criticism and take it in the spirit that it was intended -- to help you improve. If this won't work for you, then this site may not be for you.